# How to limit output from model (Resnet18 nn.linear) in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, resnet

I have problem with limitation of output values from my model (both doring model learning and afterwards).

I use to it resnet18, and Linear function

```
model_ft = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(in_features = num_ftrs, out_features= 1)
```

I'm trying to predict a normalized number (0.0,1.0)
Unfortunately, during training (and after), the model often goes beyond values.

I tried to use a sigmoid for this, but then i have optimization problems. Is there any solution to limit value (0,1) using nn.Linear?

on the forums, unfortunately, I did not find a solution to this problem.

edit:
I have only one solution for it (not very pretty): This is a modification of the loss function to punish a lot more for going over the limit. But maybe there is better solution?

Comment: you basically want to cover the entire (0, 1) range rather than saturate to either 0 or 1?

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos I want to predict the normalized angle in the interference image from 0.0 to 1.0, where 0.0 = 0deg, 1.0 = 180 deg.  Result should be smooth.

Comment: thats a hard one, periodicity is hard for NNs. For a dirty but potentially decent hack, you could use a ReLU with a non-normalized output range (0,180) which you manually clip at the output end during inference. Perhaps a bit more involved would be to check current sota at periodic activations: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402618/can-sinx-be-used-as-activation-in-deep-learning) could be a reference.